# If pressure in fluids is caused by the elastic collision of fluid molecules then why does the pressure increase with depth?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

We know that pressure in fluids increases with depth but why does it happen, if pressure is caused by the collision of particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressure also has to do with the amount of fluid which is pushing onto the surface you are talking about. In a container, for example, a surface which is at a greater depth has a larger column of fluid above it (i.e. a greater weight pushing down on it.).

The pressure on a surface at some depth $h$ is calculated as: $$P=P_o +\rho gh$$ (where $g$ is the gravitational field/acceleration in that region and $P_o$ is the atmospheric pressure.)

If you mess around with this formula a bit you will realize that this quantifies pressure in terms of the weight of the fluid column above the surface you choose.

Comment: You mean to say that if  a body was immersed into a fluid the fluid column above the body acts perpendicularly downwards on the body. But when we study buoyant force we are said that the buoyant force is caused by the pressure differences at the top of the body and the lower part of the body. You mean to say that the body immersed experiences different magnitudes of pressure at the top and the bottom you mean to say that there is more pressure at the top than at the bottom, then the body should sink because there is actually more force trying to push it down.

Comment: You misunderstood me, there *is* more pressure at a lower part of the body. (It's counter-intuitive, but this doesn't necessarily have to act perpendicularly downwards on the body.)

Comment: @Faizan: Open a tube of toothpaste. Press on the side. Toothpaste comes out of the opening. That is *perpendicular* to the direction of your pressure. That's what happens in fluids - the pressure goes quite easily "around corners".

Comment: That is an excellent example, @MikeDunlavey

Comment: Well, what would happen if you would have a bucket of water in space with negligible force of gravity acting upon it, would it still exert the same pressure. @Mike_Dunlavey

Comment: @HritikNarayan isn't the weight of the fluid above balanced by the forces applied by the fluid upwards which is probably because of elastic collision of fluid molecules? To maintain incompressibility?

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't answer the question. The question is how this formula is explained "by the elastic collision of fluid molecules".

Answer (score 0):

"Collision of particles" is just one way that particles can repel each other. They can just be near each other and not want to be so near. That's what happens in fluids -- particles get pushed closer, and they repel more, which is what pressure is.